# Are the libs still coping?

Tags: meaning

Does "Are the libs still coping?" mean "Are the liberals still dealing with their problems?"

I've checked up the word "coping" - *cope* means "struggle" or "deal", hence the guess above.

> ...just my luck to get into an accident right after the 2016 election. Of course the first thing I'm going to do is check in with my MAGA bros! So how's it been?! **Are the libs still coping?** Oh man, what a bunch of pussies. Your candidate lost! Get over it! ([source](https://archive.4plebs.org/pol/thread/297288000/))

Comment: I would define _cope_ as 'manage to get along in spite of problems'.